# Why do prices ending in 99, e.g., 0.99, 199 or 1999.9 convince consumers to buy?

Tags: consumer-psychology, neuromarketing

Why are people more likely to buy articles with a price of \$199, rather than the same (or let's say a slightly better) article for \$200?

On which human brain centre is this advertising focused? Is this some kind of manipulation?

Comment: The phenomenon is called a "price threshold", there is a lot of research on it: http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=price+threshold

Comment: Thank you for _naming_ it... it's good point to start there!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An interesting article relating to your first question is the ["Analyzing the Psychology of Pricing"](http://pricingsolutions.com/index.php/en/publications/pricing-for-researchers1/12-publications/newsletter/88-analyzing-the-psychology-of-pricing), where they suggest that consumers don't really notice any change in units of 10, e.g. \$54 vs \$59.99 etc.

In answer to the 2nd of your queries about what part of the brain is affected, here is some research that I found.

According to the article ["Marketing actions can modulate neural
representations of experienced pleasantness"](http://odohertylab.org/Publications/Plassmann2008_PNAS.pdf) (Plassman et al. 2007), very little is known about the neural responses to marketing.  However, they tested the hypothesis that

> marketing
>   actions, such as changes in the price of a product, can affect neural
>   representations of experienced pleasantness.

In another of that author's papers ["Branding the brain: A critical review and outlook"](http://www.chilleesys.com/scp/assets/plassmann.pdf) (which includes diagrams of the parts of the brain affected), he bases the process on the parts of the brain that control

> (1) representation and attention, (2) predicted value, (3) experienced
>   value, and (4) remembered value and learning.

This is also something that many in marketing are actively pursuing, according to ["Neuroeconomics: Studying Brain Responses Gives Marketers Increased Ability to Predict How People Make Decisions"](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2012/04/120424095506.htm).

Comment: @tsykora you're most welcome, I am glad I could have helped.  Thank you to Jeromy Anglim for fixing that formatting error.. not sure how it got in there.